# Adding Play JSON Library to sbt

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1

How can I add the Play JSON library (`play.api.libs.json`) to my sbt project?

When I added the following to my `plugins.sbt` file:

```
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```

I faced this error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: play#sbt-plugin;2.1.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I did not find a resolver for this library, otherwise I would've added it and ran `sbt update`. Note that my `resolvers` includes http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/.

Comment: Kevin, can you change your answer b/c now you can in play 2.2.

Comment: Hi Blankman. I think that the below [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20475410/409976) handles `play 2.2`, no?

Comment: I can't edit and change the answer, it seems to be locked.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Play 2.3 JSON with SBT >= 0.13.5**

put into build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.4"
```

**Play 2.1**

build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

scalaVersion := "2.10.2"

libraryDependencies += "play" % "play_2.10" % "2.1.0"
```

Play JSON is in Play 2.1 not an independent artifact.

Comment: At the time of writing this was true, not it is an independent lib.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Using sbt 13.11.  It cannot find com.typesafe.play#play-json_2.10;2.3.4. Probably due to me scala version being 2.10.5. I had to add the typesafe repo

Comment: on Maven Central is this version: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.typesafe.play%7Cplay-json_2.10%7C2.3.10%7Cjar

Comment: had to add the `resolvers += ...` line even for Play 2.3 and SBT > 0.13.5, and reload. Then worked.

Answer (score 78):

Play 2.2 is out and can be added separately from rest of Play Framework. in build.sbt:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.2.1"
```

Comment: Just what I wanted to find - Perfect timing on your answer!

Comment: +1. After updating your `build.sbt` with @Carolis's answer, remember to reload in `sbt`.

Comment: @JeroenKransen I can't change the answer, it is locked.

Comment: Excellent. But only works with Scala 2.10 (see @Raul's answer for 2.11+ compatibility).

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me (scala 2.11)

`resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"`

`libraryDependencies +=  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.0"`

Comment: The only answer thus far that works with Scala 2.11.

Comment: I didn't need to add the resolvers line. By the way, current version is 2.5.4, not 2.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the Play JSON library:

`addSbtPlugin("play" % "play-json" % "2.2-SNAPSHOT")`

You may also have to include the following resolver:

`"Mandubian repository snapshots" at "https://github.com/mandubian/mandubian-mvn/raw/master/snapshots/"`

Here's where I originally got the info: http://mandubian.com/2013/02/21/play-json-stand-alone/

Comment: Hmm I got a missing dependency error from adding the 1 liner. Any way to avoid the git link?

Comment: Now available truly standalone as "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.2.0". See comment by Mandubian in that blog post link "since play 2.2, you don't need my repo anymore"

Answer (score 1):

One could check [the Getting Started section of the GitHub repository](https://github.com/playframework/play-json#getting-started) and add the following to the `build.sbt` file:

> ```
> libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0-M1"
> ```