# add dependency to scala SBT project (import play.api.libs.json.Json)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm new to Scala and SBT.

I'm following this example: [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJson)

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

val json: JsValue = Json.parse("""
{ 
"user": {
"name" : "toto",
"age" : 25,
"email" : "toto@jmail.com",
"isAlive" : true,
"friend" : {
  "name" : "tata",
  "age" : 20,
  "email" : "tata@coldmail.com"
 }
} 
}
""")
```

How do you put the dependency for this library in the build.sbt file?

I'm using the Intellij scala IDE community edition.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This should already be included in a Play application. No need to add anything to the build.sbt file.

Here's how to create a new application: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/NewApplication

For information, here's the build.sbt that gets generated automatically when creating the app this way:

```
name := """app-name"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  ws
)
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Following your comment, according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436069/adding-play-json-library-to-sbt), the dependency would be:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"    
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.4"
```

Comment: Thanks @dangig , I have the community edition of Intellij which doesn't have the Play Plug-in. I just want to use the this library: **play.api.libs.json._** I have a basic SBT project set up. Can I add the dependency to the build.sbt file? This is my build.sbt file? organization := "scala"

name := "HelloSBT"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

Comment: You may try this:  resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"   and then:  libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.4"   Source:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436069/adding-play-json-library-to-sbt

Comment: I've modified the answer to include this information.